# Combine same-index objects of two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have two arrays of objects, like so:

```
var arr1 = [{name: 'Jay'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
var arr2 = [{age: 22}, {age: 30}];
```

I want a combined array like so:

```
var arr3 = [{name: 'jay', age: 22}, {name: 'Bob', age: 30}];
```

You can safely assume that the two initial arrays will have indexes matching each other, meaning index 0 of arr1 will always go with index 0 of arr2.

What would be the fastest way to accomplish this? I was imagining a `forEach` loop nested inside another `forEach` loop and extending each object from `arr1` with the current object from `arr2`, but I feel this may be too complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just iterate one array and create a new array using the index from the first iteration.  There are many ways to do this.  Here's one:

```js
    var arr1 = [{name: 'Jay'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
    var arr2 = [{age: 22}, {age: 30}];

    var combined = arr1.map(function(item, index) {
        return {name: item.name, age: arr2[index].age};
    });
    document.write(JSON.stringify(combined));
```

If you really want the maximum performance, you'd have to test a number of schemes in a number of different browsers.  For example, sometimes a `for` loop is faster than the built-in array methods in some browsers.

```js
var arr1 = [{name: 'Jay'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
var arr2 = [{age: 22}, {age: 30}];
var combined = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  combined[i] = {name: arr1[i].name, age: arr2[i].age};
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(combined));
```

FYI, the `for` loop option (the second option) looks quite a bit faster in all three browsers here in [a jsperf](http://jsperf.com/merge-object-arrays).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**In a for loop:**

```js
var arr1 = [{name: 'Jay'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
var arr2 = [{age: 22}, {age: 30}];


for(var i in arr1)
{
  arr1[i]['age'] = arr2[i]['age'];
}

console.log(arr1) //[Object { name="Jay",  age=22}, Object { name="Bob",  age=30}]
```

Now you have the merged result in arr1.

Answer (score 0):

the most trivial solution is (in compare to any util lib like underscore.js or similar). pros of it is it works without any dependency.

```
var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i+= 1) {
  item = {};
  item.name = arr1[i].name;
  item.age = arr2[i].age;
  result.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more loosely coupled solution would be by using [`merge`](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) functionality of lodash library.

This will be independent of the number of keys and key names you have in object. So in future if you decide to add keys to your object, you won't need to update the code to merge your objects.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var arr1 = [{name: 'Jay'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
var arr2 = [{age: 22}, {age: 30}];
var arr3 = [];

for (var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    arr3.push(_.merge(arr1[i], arr2[i]));
}

console.log(arr3);
```