# Merge two arrays by index value by different value in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge, array-combine

I have two arrays and I want to merge the values of the two arrays into a single array, but both arrays have different values.

Example:

```
var arr1 = [
            { data1: 1 ,data2: "value1"},
            { data1: 1 ,data2: "value2"},
            { data1: 2, data2: "value3"},
            { data1: 3 ,data2: "value3"},
            { data1: 3 ,data2: "value3"}
          ];
var arr2 = [
            { data1:1, data3:"val1"}, 
            { data1: 1, data3: "val2"},
            { data1: 2, data3: "val1"},
            { data1: 3, data3: "val1"},
            { data1: 3, data3: "val2"}
           ]; 
var arr3 = [
             { data1:1, data2: "value1", data3:"val1"}, 
             { data1: 1, data2: "value2", data3: "val2"},
             { data1: 2, data2: "value3", data3: "val1"},
             { data1: 3, data2: "value3", data3: "val1" },
             { data1: 3, data2: "value3", data3: "val2" }
           ];
```

I tried this it, will work fine when data1 is unique, but the problem is when data1 is repeating it merges the first value:

```
var data = _.map(arr1, function(item){
                return _.extend(item, _.findWhere(arr2, { dataid: item.dataid }));
           });
```

Comment: do you want to merge by index or by `data1`? if by the last, how do you distinguish between same values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine same-index objects of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076624/combine-same-index-objects-of-two-arrays) and [How to merge each object within arrays by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919164)

Comment: Note to author: You have some syntax errors in your first snippet.

Comment: I fixed typo error and  it was solved by issue by @Maheer Ali

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` and merge the properties of first and second array on same index.

```js
var arr1 = [ { data1: 1 ,data2: "value1"}, { data1: 1 ,data2: "value2"},{ data1: 2, data2: "value3"}, { data1: 3 ,data2: "value3"}, { data1: 3 ,data2: "value3"} ]; 
var arr2 = [ { data1:1, data3:"val1"}, { data1: 1, data3: "val2"}, { data1: 2, data3: "val1"}, { data1: 3, data3: "val1"}, { data1: 3, data3: "val2"} ];

const res = arr1.map((x,i) => ({...x,...arr2[i]}));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: yes its working fine in my code satisfied . @Maheer Ali

Comment: but it works in node js 6.0 version .... @Maheer Ali