# Combine array items based on their key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, key

I would like to combine two different arrays into one array based on the position of the items inside them.

The array I have now:

```
var firstName = {'John','Joe','Kees'};
var lastName = {'Smith','Fisherman','Cow'};
```

The result I would like to have:

```
var name = {'John Smith', 'Joe Fisherman', 'Kees Cow'};
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is like zipping the arrays. Maybe this question can put you on the right path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015684/how-do-i-zip-two-arrays-in-javascript

Or a bit simpler is iterating over 1 array while adding the values of the second array by index, which should work if the arrays have the same length: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076624/combine-same-index-objects-of-two-arrays

Comment: You are showing object but not array. Are you sure it's object/array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototypr.map` has a overloaded variant that gets both the value and the index of each value while iterating.
You could use it to match each value of `firstName` to the corresponding `lastName`:

```js
var firstName = ['John','Joe','Kees'];
var lastName = ['Smith','Fisherman','Cow'];

var name = firstName.map((value, index) => value + ' ' + lastName[index]);

console.log(name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew it had to be something simple like this.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Array#map` to map between the two given arrays.

In each `map` iteration, take the firstName `f` from the first array and its corresponding index `i` and use it to get the full name by combining the firstName and the lastName from the index `i`:

```js
var firstName = ['John','Joe','Kees'];
var lastName = ['Smith','Fisherman','Cow'];

const combine = (firstName, lastName) => {
  return firstName.map((f, i) => `${f} ${lastName[i] || ""}`);
}

console.log(combine(firstName, lastName));
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this one. But it is not memory or time efficient. You can make faster version with for loop.

Good luck.

```
let firstName = ['John','Joe','Kees'];
let lastName = ['Smith','Fisherman','Cow'];


const combiner = (firstArray, secondArray) => Array(Math.max(firstArray.length, secondArray.length)).fill('').map((_, i) => `${firstArray[i] || ''} ${secondArray[i] || ''}`.trim());
```

// edit:
with for loop

```
const fasterCombiner = (fa, sa) => {
  let result = [], length = fa.length > sa.length ? fa.length : sa.length;
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    result.push(`${fa[i] || ''} ${sa[i] || ''}`.trim());
  }
  return result;
}
```